# Injective dimension is infinite?

Tags: rt.representation-theory, ra.rings-and-algebras, homological-algebra

Let $A$ be a non-selfinjective finite dimensional algebra and $M$ a nonprojective module with $Ext^{i}(M,A)=0$ for all $i \geq 1$. It is easy to see that $M$ has infinite projective dimension. Does $M$ also have infinite injective dimension? (all modules finite dimensional)

Comment: is $A$ assumed commutative?

Comment: No, but feel free to say something about the commutative case. (where any module should have projective/injective dimension zero or infinite so the question is wheter $M$ can be injective)